# Getting input from arrow keys

Tags: c++, arrays, arrow-keys

I need to code a 2D array and one player in the array, and then I want to move the player with the arrow keys. 
I googled for methods and libraries and found `kbhit()`, `#include <conio.h>`, however those are outdated already.
I do not know why this kind of common questions' answers are not available on the web easily.

I am using windows 7 and VS 2015 C++.

Comment: This is way too broad. What you need to do is break down the problem into tasks and tackle them one at a time: create 2D array, acquire input from arrow keys, move player in array according to key pressed, print array, ...

Answer (score 1):

I usually use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) for this kind of stuff. It could help you a little with image manipulation as well, with the down side that you will have to use it for image rendering as well. To get key input you use:

`char key_input = waitKey(0);` and then check for key_input's value.